# JQuery events cause page reload. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm observing a behavior where onClick events cause a page to reload.

```
$('#target').click(function(){
    $('#target').hide();
})
```

So the object is shown, it hides on click, but then page reloads and the object is shown again. I'm working on a website that was setup before me, so I'm not entirely aware of all its parts. Any idea what might cause this behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: How is this marked with a `php` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a

```
return false;
```

as last statement so that the link is not called, only you function (onclick) is executed.

Comment: It's preferred to use `event.preventDefault();` as it **only** prevents the default behavior and doesn't stop the propagation...`return false;` does both.

Comment: It also isn't mostly good practice to do multiple events on the same action... (return false is simply smarter)

Comment: That's incredibly wrong. `return false;` is rarely what you actually want...`event.preventDefault();` is usually what you want.

Comment: @bwoebi I bind multiple events to the same action all the time .. I didn't realize I was doing mostly bad practice...

Comment: Is this irony? It's my opinion; everybody may have a different opinion about it...

Answer (score 7):

You need to prevent the default event behavior with `event.preventDefault`:

```
$("#target").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Using `return false` will also work, but it [does more than you may intend](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

This is in line with the [event cancellation standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation-h3)